# Nokia 925 denim os as mass storage

Tags: windows-phone-8, local-storage, app-data, usb-mass-storage, lumia

How to connect Nokia lumia 925 denim os as mass storage in windows 8 or mac os, so i could explore root folder, I basically need this for copying app data?

I ve tried the Guide "Put the phone in mass storage mode" mentioned in [Mass_storage_mode_and_boot_configuration_data](https://dev.windowsphone.com/it-it/OEM/docs/Debugging/Mass_storage_mode_and_boot_configuration_data)

But it ain't work in my device, it is just restarting normally.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can only browse shared folders such as Documents, Pictures, Music and Videos.

However there's a tool which allows to locate and fetch files inside `IsolatedStorage`, have a look at the Codeplex page: https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/

Comment: I tried isostore spy on windows 7 desktop, but its Not detecting my device in list. Is there any alternative for the isostore spy??

Comment: Should I register my phone as dev device??

Comment: Wait, if you didn't register your phone as developer how you are supposed to develop apps on the device?

Comment: Am not developing the app, i wanted to transfer app data from my lumia 925 to other windows phone, so i want to explore root folder so that i can find the app files. And the isostore spy dint work for me in windows 7 as well as windows 8, should i register my phone and try it??

Comment: If the app data is not saved in shared folders you can't get it

Comment: I want transfer the whatsapp data base file (whatsapp chat history) from lumia 925 to other windows phone , is it possible anyways??